# flatten and filter a tree json object using jq

Tags: jq

How can I filter and flatten a tree-like json object using `jq` so that it's only applied to leaves of the tree? In the example below I'd like jq to return something like `[{"name": "foo1"}, {"name": "bar"}]`

```
obj = {
    "name": "root",
    "nodes": [
        {"name": "foo1"},
        {"name": "foo2", nodes = [
            {"name": "bar"}
        ]}
    ]
}
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON

Comment: as if that's the relevant thing here

Comment: It literally is when you are posting questions about `jq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[ recurse(.nodes[]?) | select(has("nodes")|not) ]
```

This walks the tree and retains all nodes that do not have a `nodes` key themselves.

Answer (score 0):

demo
https://jqplay.org/s/Xrgqos4W-M

```
filter:
[recurse(.nodes[]?) | select(has("nodes") | not) | {name:.name}]

input:
{
    "name": "root",
    "nodes": [
        {"name": "foo1"},
        {"name": "foo2", 
        "nodes": [
            {"name": "bar"}
        ]}
    ]
}

ouput:
[{"name":"foo1"},{"name":"bar"}]
```